# Multiple forms with shared fields

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms

How to make multiple forms with shared fields?

```
<input type=text name=username />
<form action="/users">
    ... some fields ...
</form>
<form action="/admins">
    ... some another fields ...
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having two forms share an element is not possible without JavaScript.

You can't have two form elements overlap or nest each other; so, a form element can't be in two forms at once.

What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, now I know that I can't resolve the problem without js. The question is updated

Answer (score 1):

You really only need one form if youre processing server side. just use array naming for the form fields and submit buttons like:

```
global[my-field-name]
action[specific-submit-action]
specific-submit-action[my-field-name]
```

then in what ever you are using to process you can merge/combine the  `specific-submit-action` and `global` arrays/hashes and do things with the data depending on the `action[specific-submit-action]`.